# Facebook App Policy : incentivizes users to use Facebook social channels

Tags: facebook

This may be a controversial topic.

I have an app that just banned by Facebook, which is reported that the app violates Facebook App Policy (VI. 1)

> Your app gates content behind or incentivizes users to use Facebook
>   social channels. (FPP IV.1)

Here is the Facebook App Flow:

1. Click "Page Tab App" icon
2. Enter the landing page, check whether the user installs the App or not; If not installed, install the App
3. Enter the checking page, check whether the user likes a Fans page, share to wall & send friend requests; If not, the user will not allow to go to next step.
4. Next page is a questionnaire; user has to complete the questionnaire to go to next step
5. Last page is a Thank You page

The whole idea is, the user has to complete the flow to enter a lucky draw (prize will be given to winners).

My question is, how to avoid violating the rule?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

It's pretty straight forward...

You are telling the user that he **must** like a page, share to his wall and invite his friends, all of those are social channels which you "force" the user to go through in order to use your app.

You can ask your users to like your page, you can ask them to invite their friends (or better yet offer them a better experience when their friends join), but you can not (and that's the policy violation) incentivize them to do so by saying "do that or don't use the app"

Comment: You mean that I should not force users to like a page / share message ?

Comment: Yes, that's right. You can give them the option and ask them to do so, but you can not force them to use any social channel that facebook provides you with.

Comment: but there are so many apps around that force users to like their page before continue the flow.

Comment: The fact that other break the "law" does not make it right for you to do so, I bet that you can think of plenty of good examples from the "real world" as well. As for "why me?", maybe a user(s) complained about your app specifically, or maybe you just passed a certain threshold, you see facebook won't check everything for every app, but once certain apps start being big enough they will start checking them.